# How can i upload an image to my website and set it on my card component?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, filereader

I want to receive some information by using a form and then by submitting the form create a card based on that information, when i upload the image i can not set it as the card picture and i face with this error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo8EO.jpg)

```
const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState("");


const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  console.log(file);
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (file) => {
    setImgUrl(reader.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 };


<Form.Group controlId="formFileSm" className="mb-3">
<Form.Label>Upload a picture</Form.Label>
<Form.Control type="file" size="sm" onChange={onChangeHandler} />
</Form.Group>
```

`my Card Component`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const items = this.props.items.map((item) => {
      if (item.imgUrl) {
        return (
          <div className="card col-md-2">
            <img src={require(`${item.imgUrl}`)} className="img-fluid" />
            <h4 className="pt-4">name : {item.name}</h4>
            <span className="pb-2">PhoneNumber : {item.phoneNumber}</span>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <div className="card col-md-2">
            <img src={require("../image/3user.jpg")} className="img-fluid" />
            <h4 className="pt-4">name : {item.name}</h4>
            <span className="pb-2">PhoneNumber : {item.phoneNumber}</span>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid row justify-content-center">{items}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Why are you using `require`? The image URL should be used directly as the `src`, require is for loading JS modules.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny in creat-react-app you can use `require` to load local images. It won't work just by passing relative url

Comment: @Konrad I know this is tagged with CRA but in the error message, it seems `require` thinks it's a module.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny yes, it should be `src={item.imgUrl}` instead of `src={require(`${item.imgUrl}`)}`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)